# Is space allowed between #! and /bin/bash in shebang?

Tags: shebang

In a shebang, is a space or more allowed between `#!` and the interpreter?

For example, `#!               /bin/bash`. It seems work, but some said that it is incorrect.

Comment: Read http://www.in-ulm.de/~mascheck/various/shebang/#blankrequired

Comment: So a space is not *necessary*? I've always seen at least one...

Comment: @Bakuriu Where? I've almost *never* seen one...

Answer (score 83):

**Yes, this is allowed.**

The Wikipedia article [about the shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)#History)  includes a 1980 email from Dennis Ritchie, when he was introducing kernel support for the shebang (as part of a wider package called *interpreter directives*) into Version 8 Unix (emphasis mine):

> The system has been changed so that if a file being executed
>   begins with the magic characters `#!`, the rest of the line is understood
>   to be the name of an interpreter for the executed file. […]
>
> To take advantage of this wonderful opportunity,
>   put
>
> ```
> #! /bin/sh
> ```
>
> at the left margin of the first line of your shell scripts.
>   **Blanks after `!` are OK.**

So spaces after the shebang have been around for quite a while, and indeed, Dennis Ritchie’s example is using them.

Note that early versions of Unix had a limit of 16 characters in this interpreter line, so you couldn’t have an arbitrary amount of whitespace there. This restriction no longer applies in modern kernels.

Comment: Note that the character limit still exists on linux at least - and is 127. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/10813634/6857772

Answer (score 47):

Yes, blanks are allowed after the `#!`.  There was even a (mistaken) thought that some systems might require it, but it has always just been optional.

For further reading try [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20170215070707/http://www.in-ulm.de/~mascheck/various/shebang/#details)

Answer (score 11):

FYI, some versions of systemd fail to parse shebangs with a space. With a service like this:

```
[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/root/foo.sh
```

... and a shebang like this:

```
#! /bin/bash
```

... you may get an error like this:

```
systemd[32834]: foo.service: Failed at step EXEC spawning /root/foo.sh: Exec format error
```

Removing the space from the shebang fixes the error. So look out for that one.

Comment: Ah. yet another reason for me to be grumpy about systemd; Just what I needed… Thanks for the heads-up.

Comment: FWIW, I can't reproduce with systemd 245.4-4ubuntu3.6 (on Ubuntu 20.04).

Comment: The only reference to `shebang` I find in the source code of systemd is in `./test/test-functions` about a `_shebang_regex='(#! *)(/[^ ]+).*'` (from someone who doesn't know that bash regexps are not anchored apparently) which explicitly allows those spaces (but is not otherwise related to executing services).

Comment: I'm not sure why systemd would want to parse shebangs by itself. Also, I'd expect a "no such file or directory" error if systemd tried to execute `" /bin/bash"` instead of `"/bin/bash"`. It all suggests systemd is fine but your issue was elsewhere. Maybe you had a UTF-8 BOM at the start of your `#! /bin/bash` script?

Comment: I just see the obvious system call too, `execve("/root/test.sh", ["/root/test.sh"], [/* 6 vars */]) = 0` So, no, this doesn't seem to be true. (tested on a way older systemd, though)