# Is it possible to modify the error message triggered by the parameter expansion using the "${pattern:?word}" format?

Tags: shell, posix

Suppose that I've got the following script called `test.sh`:

```
#! /bin/sh -
printf '%s\n' "${1:?empty or missing argument}"
```

When run without any command-line arguments it behaves like this:

```
$ ./test.sh
./test.sh: 2: ./test.sh: 1: empty or missing argument
```

**Question:** Is it possible to change the *"./test.sh: 2:"* part of the error message?

Comment: Note that `${1:?missing argument}` would not check whether `$1` is missing but if it's empty (and the script could be given one empty argument). For _missing_, you'd need `${1?missing argument}` instead. In any case, if you care about the format, you might as well do it the long way like with `if [ "$#" -eq 0 ]; then...` (missing) or `if [ -z "$1" ]` (empty).

Comment: @jimmij From what I read it is perfectly ok to put a space after `#!`. (For example in the book _Classic Shell Scripting_ chapter _2.4_ and here https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/276751/128489.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to your question is 'no'; using that syntax shall output the script, line number, and variable referenced to standard error as you describe.  If you want to alter this, pipe standard error into a process to massage it into your desired format in a script which itself runs the script outputting the error message.

Comment: Why is the script name mentioned twice in the message?

Comment: Unable to replicate this.  stderr of `./se.sh: line 2: 1: whoops` with a script containing a shebang line and output statement.

Comment: I'm on Ubuntu so my `/bin/sh` is probably Dash. I experience the same behaviour as you do when I use Bash instead.

Comment: A sound hypothesis; I tested on the `sh` that comes with McBSD.