# How do I process a variable?

Tags: find, xargs

I want to process a group of files.

```
pi@raspberrypi:~/A6.1 $ ls -1

0bd57df4.code
0bd57df4.enc
3189204c.code
3189204c.enc
39f831fb.code
39f831fb.enc
68ff6d19.code
68ff6d19.enc
find.sh
test.sh
```

I run a script (`find.sh`) that searches for files by the mask, and runs another script (`test.sh`) and passes the name of the found file to the parameter.

In test mode, I want to display the full file name and the shortened name without an extension.

The contents of the file find.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash

find -name '*.enc' -printf "%f\0" | xargs -0 -n 1 ./test.sh
```

The contents of the file test.sh:

```
# !/bin/bash

NAMEFILE=$1
FULLNAME=$NAMEFILE
CUTNAME=`echo ${NAMEFILE:0:6}`
echo "FULLNAME - "$FULLNAME
echo "FILENAME - $CUTNAME"
```

The full name is displayed, there is no shortened name. Gives an error message. How do I process a variable?

```
pi@raspberrypi:~/A6.1 $ ./find.sh
./test.sh: 1: ./test.sh: Bad substitution
FULLNAME - 68ff6d19.enc
FILENAME -
./test.sh: 1: ./test.sh: Bad substitution
FULLNAME - 3189204c.enc
FILENAME -
./test.sh: 1: ./test.sh: Bad substitution
FULLNAME - 39f831fb.enc
FILENAME -
./test.sh: 1: ./test.sh: Bad substitution
FULLNAME - 0bd57df4.enc
FILENAME -
```

When I run the test.sh file, it works.

```
pi@raspberrypi:~/A6.1 $ ./test.sh 68ff6d19.code
FULLNAME - 68ff6d19.code
CUTNAME - 68ff6d19
```

Comment: It works well for me, are you sure you described the problem correctly?

Comment: I *think* the issue is that your shebang is malformed (`# !/bin/bash` should be `#!/bin/bash` or `#! /bin/bash`) so the `./test.sh` script is being executed by `xargs` default shell, which is likely `sh`

Comment: Steeldriver, thank you very much, it helped me

Comment: @steeldriver Spaces are allowed after the `#!`. See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/276751/is-space-allowed-between-and-bin-bash-in-shebang  But not between the `#` and the `!`.

Comment: @Kusalananda Agreed - that's why I said "should be `#!/bin/bash` **or** `#! /bin/bash`" - the OP has a `# !` (hash-space-bang)

Answer (score 0):

I have the feeling you might be able to concentrate your code by using GNU Parallel:

```
find -name '*.enc' | parallel echo Full:{} Cut:{.}
```

Or if the code is more complicated:

```
#!/bin/bash

doit() {
  FULLNAME="$1"
  CUTNAME="$2"
  echo "FULLNAME - $FULLNAME"
  echo "FILENAME - $CUTNAME"
}
export -f doit

find -name '*.enc' | parallel doit {} {.}
```

Answer (score 0):

The error comes from running the script with `/bin/sh` which does not have the particular parameter expansion that you use.  You are using `/bin/sh` because you have  a space between the `#` and the `!` on the first line.

Spaces are allowed *after* the `!`: [Is space allowed between #! and /bin/bash in shebang?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/276751/is-space-allowed-between-and-bin-bash-in-shebang)

Also related: [Which shell interpreter runs a script with no shebang?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/373223/which-shell-interpreter-runs-a-script-with-no-shebang)

---

You can easily get away with a single script here:

```
find . -type f -name '*.enc' -exec bash -c '
    for n do
        n=${n##*/}
        printf "Full name:\t%s\n" "$n"
        printf "Cut name:\t%s\n"  "${n:0:6}"
    done' sh {} +
```

Running this on the filenames that you present will produce

```
Full name:      0bd57df4.enc
Cut name:       0bd57d
Full name:      3189204c.enc
Cut name:       318920
Full name:      39f831fb.enc
Cut name:       39f831
Full name:      68ff6d19.enc
Cut name:       68ff6d
```

If you just want to remove the extension:

```
find . -type f -name '*.enc' -exec sh -c '
    for n do
        n=${n##*/}
        printf "Full name:\t%s\n" "$n"
        printf "Cut name:\t%s\n"  "${n%.*}"
    done' sh {} +
```

This yields

```
Full name:      0bd57df4.enc
Cut name:       0bd57df4
Full name:      3189204c.enc
Cut name:       3189204c
Full name:      39f831fb.enc
Cut name:       39f831fb
Full name:      68ff6d19.enc
Cut name:       68ff6d19
```