# How to write a script such that I can pipe it to find?

Tags: pipe, xargs

I have a script that expects files as arguments, and for each executes a set of instructions. How should I write it to be able to pipe it to `find`? In the example below, I haven't used `find` as such. I assume its output has the same structure as `printf "%s\n..."` (has it not?)

`my-script.sh`:

```
# !/bin/bash

help()
{
    echo "help"
    echo
}

while [[ $# -gt 0 ]]
do
    case $1 in
        *)
            echo "$1"
            shift # past argument
            ;;
    esac
done
```

Fine:

```
$ cat foo; echo; cat bar
foo  

bar
$ ./my-script.sh foo bar
foo
bar
```

But then:

```
$ printf "%s\n%s\n" "./foo" "./bar" | xargs -n 1 ./my-script.sh
./my-script.sh: 9: ./my-script.sh: [[: not found
./my-script.sh: 9: ./my-script.sh: [[: not found
```

Comment: Seek for error in line 14 of actual script

Comment: You show the code for `my-script.sh` but you're piping to `foo.sh`. Can you show the actual code that is failing? You can also checkout [shellcheck](https://shellcheck.net) for help.

Comment: @doneal24 the code is now copy pasted from `cat my-script.sh`

Comment: Your shebang `# !/bin/bash` is broken I think - you may have whitespace *after* `#!` but not *between* the `#` and the `!`. Likely `xargs` is defaulting to `/bin/sh` in this case - which doesn't support the ksh/bash/zsh `[[ ... ]]` extended test construct

Comment: ... whereas when you run it directly from your (bash?) interactive shell, it's likely being executed using bash in spite of the broken shebang. See for example [Which shell interpreter runs a script with no shebang?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/373229/65304)

Comment: @steeldriver problem solved.

Comment: @Erwann OK I have turned it into an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your shebang

```
# !/bin/bash
```

is invalid (it just looks like a comment). Whitespace [is permitted after the `#!`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/276751/is-space-allowed-between-and-bin-bash-in-shebang), but not between the `#` and the `!`.

Because of that, the script run via `xargs` is being interpreted by `/bin/sh` - which does not support the `[[ ... ]]` extended test syntax (originally from `ksh`).

When you run the script directly from your interactive shell instead of via `xargs`, it is likely being interpreted by a bash child shell. See [Which shell interpreter runs a script with no shebang?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/373229/65304)